# magento2 cart product miss when regist new account login

Tags: magento

The visitor added the product to the shopping cart. After registering a new user, the quote_item_option part of the information was deleted. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you check same in fresh magento ?